# django add relationships to user model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django project using the built in user model.

I need to add relationships to the user. For now a "like" relationship for articles the user likes and a "following" relationship for other users followed.

What's the best way to define these relationships? The django doc recommends creating a Profile model with a one on one relation to the user to add fields to the user. but given no extra fields will be added to the user profile in my case this is overkill.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you want the reverse relations?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams how can I do that on a "following" relationship it's self referencing relationship?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For these special many-to-many relationships, you have to define them in models:

```
class UserFollowing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='following')
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='followed_by')
```

So then if you have a user, you can do things like:

```
user = User.objects.get(...)
user.following.all() # all users this user is following
user.followed_by.all() # all users who follow this user
```

As for articles, you have setup a similar schema:

```
class ArticleLike(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='likes')
    like = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='articles_like')

Article.objects.get(...).likes.all()

User.objects.get(...).articles_like.all()
```

Comment: Even though not ideal, this seems like the most practical solution at the moment. For the likes, no need to define a separate model, a ManyToMany field in the article model does it

Comment: True, unless you want to be able to see who liked the article (like in Facebook). Also I did not mention in the question, but you can create many-to-many relationships using the `ManyToManyField` which will create the intermediate table by itself.

Answer (score 1):

On the currently released Django version(s) [ up to 1.4.x ], the standard practice is to define a profile object. This is preferable to "polluting" the built in user model by extending / modifying it. The upcoming version of Django will allow the creation of [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-custom-user).

In summary:

- The cleanest solution that can be used with a current production version of Django is to create a profile model and place the "like" and "follow" relationships there
- The next version of Django will allow you to supply your own User model - that has exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the [Django Relationships](https://github.com/coleifer/django-relationships) app for this. It is meant for creating relationships between `auth.users` and you will understand how to create self-referential follows by studying that code. You can then extend it for more generic types or write your own using the [Django Content Types Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

However since Django ORM inherently isn't exactly defined to be a graph database, you should try to stick to relational database concepts and use a `ManyToMany` Relationship or `ForeignKey` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ManytoMany relationship in your article to the User model. Everytime a user likes one article add him into it. Length of that field will be the number of like in that article.

Comment: Never modify the `User` model.

Comment: I thought what I said is to add a MantoManyField to User model in his Article model, not inside User model.